# Spin rotation of masses in a rotating gravitational field around a black hole

Tags: gravity, black-holes, kerr-metric, frame-dragging

If a rotational gravitational field affects masses in the way the frame and body velocities are added together does it mean that as the rotation of the frame has a gradient of the perpendicular velocity towards the black hole that the body affected by gravity must spin so its front is spinning away from the black hole because the part of the body in proximity of the BH feels a faster move of the frame and the farther part a slower movement of the frame?

Comment: Could you maybe rephrase the question using more than one sentence?

Comment: You seem to be asking if the rotational frame dragging causes tidal forces.

Comment: @safesphere Yes.